# Custom actions before install in windows installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I want to add a message for user if already a previous version is available when installing newer version. I am using setup project of Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project 2022.

I tried custom action to override Install method. But the action is not before execution starts. It happens only after execution completed.

Looking for pre installation action.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this exact same problem a few months ago, this is what I ended up doing...

you have to create a new WinForms project in the installer solution, and then you have to go to add a new item and find installer class in the list and write your logic there, and then link it as a custom action in the installer wherever you want it to run.

this video shows you how to do it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5MSPyT1Gr0

or you can build your installer from scratch like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLhDJoPJqzE

Comment: Thanks for your response @big-boy. This has not ended up with the need. Any custom action is only executing after installation process. base.Install(stateSaver)

Any additional input?